# Make JWT endpoint accessible by only our frontend

Tags: authentication, security, frontend, backend

I have a web application with separate frontend and backend. I use jwt authentication to protect endpoints. I have a endpoint `/api/jwt` which takes username,password and returns an `access_token`.
Now what i want is this endpoint to be accessible only by my frontend. I tried to use CORS but i still can access this endpoint through direct curl or postman.

How can i implement such restriction ?